# Does "listen 443" in NGINX redirects you from http to https automatically?

Tags: nginx

I have a simple question. I'm just wondering if I have like:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ...
}
```

Does this automatically redirect me from http to https if I enter URL http://example.com?

It works for me but I'm not really sure if it works for everyone, that's why I'm asking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it doesn't, if it is "working" for you, then it isn't this bit of config that is doing it

Comment: If you are using Strict-Transport-Security you may be seeing the client's browser redirecting from http to https automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I am using this header:
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
Do I have to do a manual redirection in NGINX file if I have this?

Comment: @RichardSmith That still would require first connection on port 80, or getting the site on a preload list. Infact chrome require port 80 to 443 redirection to be present even for a preload submission

Comment: @Drifter104 Are you sure? I am thinking that connecting to HTTPS with HSTS once makes the browser refuse to connect to HTTP (until max age expires). I have no experience of chrome though. Oh and I wasn't suggesting that HSTS is an answer, just an explanation for the questioner's observations.

Comment: @Drifter104 "That still would require first connection on port 80" - That's wrong. The HSTS header is not valid when served over HTTP. What the OP could have done is this: 1) Add HSTS header 2) Manually visit site over HTTPS for testing reasons 3) Try to visit again over HTTP and notices redirect

In any way a "usual" redirect is always recommend. The HSTS header is just an addition.

Comment: @rugk actually yes that is possible, but in general you either have to get a port 80 redirect to 443 to be served the HSTS header, manually type https for the first visit or be on a preload list. 2 of those 3 require you to have a port 80 redirect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, typically need something like this to do the forwarding.

If it's working already something else could be doing it. Are there any other web servers install? Are you using a CDN that might be doing it?

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  // etc - main server
}   


# Forward non-www requests to www
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=128k flush=1m if=$log_ua;
  return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/privkey;

  # Set up preferred protocols and ciphers. TLS1.2 is required for HTTP/2
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=128k flush=1m if=$log_ua;

  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I'm currently using this for redirection:
`server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;
 server_name example.com www.example.com sub1.example.com sub2.example.comt;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}`
I'm not redirecting non-www to www. Is my code good?

Comment: It looks about right to me. If it works it's good, if it doesn't then look more carefully at the example I posted above.

Comment: Hey, @Tim I'm sorry for being late, but I'd like to ask:

Comment: I'm using *.example.com for domain record, and when using that example code I posted, when I visit non-existing domain it shows that certificate is invalid, how can I fix that? Sorry for double comment by the way..